# How to split the data of the form ["1","2","3"] and store in array as [1,2,3] in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, regex, function

How to split the data of the form `["1","2","3"]` and store in array as `[1,2,3]` in `PHP`?

I need this data in order to get or fetch data from a `mysql` table which is having data as id 1 data red, id 2 data blue.  so that i need the data to be converted to **1 2 3** so that I can give it in query to fetch the data.

Please someone help me thanks.

Comment: You want to convert these strings into numbers?

Comment: Php and your database will take care of this for you with type coercion. Have you encountered an error?

Comment: yes lix in which way i have to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this will do , Run this after your **`while`** .

```
$int_arr = array_map('intval',$your_returned_array);
```

**EDIT:**

> ok am sorry it is column value in table it is totally a string which i
>   have to split as numbers

Do like this..

```
$str= '["1","2","3"]';
preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $str, $matches);
print_r(array_map('intval',$matches[1]));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: ["1","2","3"] this output which am getting is not array it is totally a string

Comment: @user3132041 -you need to explicitly state this in your question.

Comment: ok am sorry it is column value in table it is totally a string which i have to split as numbers

Comment: its working great shankar damodaran, can i ask you one more that i need to get data from table by using this by matching the id with these respective numbers can you help me for that please thanks

Comment: Please try something and then let know where you are stuck so i can help you from there. `You know very well spoonfeeding is not gonna help  at all :)`

Comment: Please edit that on your question. Not in this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Good :) Come back if you have any problems we are there to help.

Comment: hi shankar damodaran i have edited my question please check it and get me some solution please thanks.

Comment: i found solution so i removed the edited data. thanks for your help.